# postgresql : find privileges in meta informations

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.4

With PostgreSQL 9.4 on linux centos 6.6.

I give a privilege to a user with something like :

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE DBNAME_adm IN SCHEMA DBNAME_adm GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON TABLES TO DBNAME_usr;
```

I need to have a SQL statement to find if this privilege is already ok or not.
I did not find any table in pg_catalog nor information_schema which contains such an information.

Where can I find default privileges metadata ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it by myself !

Tables to be parsed to have all metadata on ACL and privileges given by ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES can be found in pg_catalog.pg_default_acl and pg_catalog.pg_namespace with the help of pg_catalog.pg_authid.

Some references :

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-default-acl.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html

Comment: results are in a array : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html